# dynamic drop-down not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to implement a dynamic drop-down list using Ajax and PHP. Based on the index value in the first option list, second one should give me list of names with that id.

select1.php :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch1.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
<center>
<div id="select_box">
 <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
  <option>Select ID</option>
  <?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'admin';
  $pass = 'admin';
  $dbname='kancha';
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "select distinct id from test";
  $select= $conn->query($sql);
  if ($select->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</option>";
       //echo "<option value=>".$row['id']."</option>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
  ?>
 </select>

 <select id="new_select">
 </select>

</div>     
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

fetch1.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'admin';
  $pass = 'admin';
  $dbname='kancha';
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $id = $_POST['get_option'];
  //echo '$id';
 $sql = "select id, name from test where id='$id'";;
 $find= $conn->query($sql);

 if ($find->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $find->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
 exit;
}
?>
```

My database looks something like this :

```
SELECT * from test; 
id  name
1   Name1
2   Name2
1   Name3
```

The first drop down works just fine. However the second drop down isn't working.
I have attached the screenshot of it as well. Is there a problem in sending data across the files or what? Not able to figure out where has the code gone wrong.

For the second option list, when I have selected **1**, I should be getting **Name1** and **Name3** as options but I get none. [image]

EDIT: Corrected javascript in select1.php

Comment: `<option>` has no `value`.

Comment: Make your response as HTML option tags and then fill that response into the second select box; where ever you have doubts just use alert statement, so that you will be confirmed that you are getting the right value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the content for `new_select` with the wrong variable.

It should be `response` rather than `val`

Change to:

```
document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response;
```

And assign value to your return options.

**Like:**

```
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
```

And change your sql string to the following for the above to work.

```
 $sql = "select id, name from test where id='$id'";
```

And make sure your `jquery.js` include is being loaded.

Comment: Did all three, didn't work.
Also added,`echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</option>";` in `select1.php`

Comment: just did. can you check it out?

Comment: in fetch1.php add - `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of your document.

Comment: In your ajax success function add - `alert(response);`

Comment: Pls comment the response.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
select_1.php:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at fetch_select (select_1.php:8)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (select_1.php:28)`

Comment: Make sure your jquery.js include is being loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. Stupid of me not to check the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Add value to the Option in selectbox, right now there is no value passing from the fetch_select()